# An include before class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What class are SecurityMethods being 'mixed' in to? I usually see the include after the class definition.

```
include SecurityMethods

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

.
.
.

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this situation, `SecurityMethods` is mixed into `Object`.

Comment: Are SecurityMethods available throughout and always in the application since they are included in Object?

Comment: @superstar3000 yes, provided this file is loaded (so it's not available in initializers, for example, because they're loaded before `ApplicationController`).

Comment: Would SecurityMethods be available in app/helpers/*.rb files?

Comment: @superstar3000 yes, they will.